# html source not refreshed after perform a click via selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get html source by `*webdriver.page_source*` of selenium, it works well the first the page was opened, but after I performed a click action by `*webdriver.find_element_by_id(id).click()*` and then execute *`webdriver.page_source*`again, the html source is still the same as the old one, can somebody advise how can I fix this? my code is as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
wd=webdriver.Chrome()
wd.get(somepage)
f=open('C:\html1.txt','w')
f.write(wd.page_source.encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
wd.find_element_by_id("to_index").click()
f=open('C:\html2.txt','w')
f.write(wd.page_source.encode('utf-8'))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it suppose to change?

Comment: Show `HTML` code of the element you try to click on or provide with `URL` of initial page

Comment: Maybe you are getting new source to quickly, try with some sleep for 5 seconds after your click just to ensure it's (not) a timing issue.

Comment: I am sure it suppose to change and the second time to use wd.page_source is after very long time

Comment: Hi all, 
I just got a workaround by using find_element_by_xxx to get the whole html after reloaded
Thank you